# how to make Html hyper link in email

Tags: android, html

i am making Hyper Link in below code ,its not  click able when i am sending it in emailt
thanks for help

```
 String url = "http://www.google.com";

      String hyperLink = "<a  ref=\"" + url + "\">"+"click"+"</a>";



StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(EmailPreText+" "+Name);
sb.append('\n');
sb.append(Html.fromHtml(hyperLink));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like this?

```
String url = "http://www.google.com";
String hyperLink = "<a  href=\"" + url + "\">"+"click"+"</a>";
```

n.b. HREF    &    //  after the protocol.

Comment: well then the problem doesn't seem to be with the code that we see. i.e. the <a> tag should work if it's actually in the email properly